# Printed Ryanair boarding pass has no QR code

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I need a printed boarding pass because I am not an EU citizen. My boarding pass looks fine on my phone… If I were able to use it as a mobile boarding pass but I am not. The printed version is incorrect as it does not show the QR code it's just scramble of characters 
 Has anyone else had this issue

Comment: That's a problem with the way you're printing it, or the printer, or maybe the phone. It's not a problem with the boarding pass itself. You might try asking on [su], and include details of phone and printer.

Comment: Perhaps you're printing the screen area and not the entire page, and the QR code doesn't appear on screen because it's beyond the area shown in the window. Make sure to use the window's scroll bars to examine the entire page.

Answer (score 4):

I've had other issues with tickets where the barcode isn't printed or even shown on the screen. **My advice is to try another PDF Viewer.** Acrobat Reader DC is a good start: https://get.adobe.com/reader/

Answer (score 3):

I actually had very similar happen the last time I used Ryanair - only I didn't actually discover the barcode hadn't printed until I arrived at the airport! I had printed all the boarding passes directly from the "Print" link on the site (i.e. not from a separate PDF viewer).

I was directed to the Ryanair checkin desk who indicated that apparently this, quote: *"Happens a lot"* and printed replacement boarding cards for me without quibble or charge.

For the return trip I downloaded the card as a pdf and *then* printed it and it worked fine.

Comment: The "Print" link is likely to be using the browser's HTML or PDF to printer conversion, so if you notice try a different browser.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan HTML rendering was my surmise as well, FWIW in this instance it was Safari on OSX. Certainly was a wake up call to actually **check** the darn printout before setting off! :D